# scalogram for huge data

Tags: wavelet

I have a huge data for which I want to apply wavelet and plot scalogram. 
the below code works for small data. However, I have a huge signal, for which I am not able to plot scalogram.

Can anyone suggest possible way to

---

```
wname = 'morl';
scales=1:64;
coefs = cwt(SignalXX1,scales,wname);%'scalCNT');
TAB_Sca2Frq = scal2frq(scales,wname,1/fs);
z=wscalogram('image',coefs,TAB_Sca2Frq,SignalXX1);
```

[image]

Comment: What sort of quantities are you looking to calculate from the scalogram? What is the purpose?

Comment: In many cases it makes no sense to plot more data than you have pixels in your screen. If you plan to zoom in, you can still decimate your data, and re-plot regions that seem interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to find the predominant and varying frequency that's occurring. my signal looks like this. (attachment in the Question)